# Is there any way to not warn about "COUNT" enum constants missing from switch in gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc-warning

If a switch with enum-type argument misses some of the constants and does not have default branch, the gcc `-Wswitch` option causes a warning like

```
warning: enumeration value 'WHATEVER' not handled in switch
```

However, many our switches are like:

```
enum foo {
    FOO_ONE,
    FOO_TWO,
    FOO_COUNT
};
```

where the FOO_COUNT never appears as value, but is used to know the number of values that are defined and may appear in the variable. Because we are indexing an array with the enum value or bit-packing it and need to check it will fit or something. Thus an enum that handles all values should *not* include this one constant. Is there a way to keep that warning, but avoid it for such special values? I.e.

```
switch(foo) {
    case FOO_ONE:
        anything;
};
```

should give a warning, but:

```
switch(foo) {
    case FOO_ONE:
        anything;
    case FOO_TWO:
        anything_else;
}
```

should **not**.

Comment: FWIW I think the problem is that your enum is in a state of sin. It contains a value that (since you don't have to handle it in the switch) is not actually a possible value of the type. That is to say, nobody should ever write `foo f = FOO_COUNT;`, but you've given them the means to do so. I suppose you don't want to write `static const int FOO_COUNT = FOO_TWO+1;` after the enum, or even `#define FOO_COUNT (FOO_TWO+1)` inside the enum, because of the risk that you'll forget to update it when you add FOO_THREE?

Comment: Another option, only slightly breaking Steve's comment:
add `FOO_LAST = FOO_TWO` into enumeration. It will not add new value into enum and you will avoid polluting preprocessor namespace (and in c++, `FOO_LAST `will be in correct namespace).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally prefer another approach: generating the `enum` through a macro to set up the count.

```
GENERATE_ENUM(foo, (FOO_ONE)(FOO_TWO))
```

will produce:

```
enum foo {
    FOO_ONE,
    FOO_TWO
};

inline size_t size(enum foo) { return 2; }
```

And thus my enum is warning free.

The macro can also be adapted to produce other useful values, such as (in the case of a discontiguous enumeration) an array of all values (in order) which may be useful to automate iteration or checking for existence, etc...

Comment: what macro syntax do you use to automatically count the number of enum values input into your GENERATE_ENUM() macro?

Comment: @ryeager: I use the Boost Preprocessor library and more specifically the [`BOOST_PP_SEQ_SIZE`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) macro which expands to the size of the sequence.

Answer (score 2):

If you already know which of your `switch`s handle all values, you can add the `default:` keyword to those, but at the same time, it will catch all other values that are not listed in your `switch-case`, so you will not be warned even if you forgot for example `case FOO_ONE:`.

```
switch(value){
    case FOO_ONE:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

You could also combine it with a macro, so that you can "enable" the warnings from one point of your code:

```
#define m_ignore_switch_case_warnings default: break
//and define it like this to enable the warnings again
#define m_ignore_switch_case_warnings

switch(value){
    case FOO_ONE:
        break;

    m_ignore_switch_case_warnings;
}
```

You will be able to "disable" the warnings for any kind of `switch` and you are not forced to update your `switch` code in case you change your enum `FOO_COUNT` or if you have different names for your count variables.

Else you are reffered to [David Rodríguez - dribeas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12110909/1548637)'s post

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it will not warn if you forget any other enumerator, which Jan seems to still want to be warned about.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to still have warnings for the rest of them, the only thing I can think of is to actually create the case:

```
switch (foo) {
...
case FOO_COUNT: //empty
}
```

Comment: Either that, or an empty `default:` clause. Can't think of any extremely obvious reasons to prefer one over the other, though...

Comment: @twalberg: the reason to prefer `case FOO_COUNT:` over `default:` is in order to still get the warning when you forget to include `FOO_TWO` in the switch (or when you later add `FOO_THREE` to the enum and forget to update the switch). `default:` means "handle everything", what we want is "handle the special value only".

Comment: @SteveJessop Good point... I was thinking more of the code generated by the two cases, which should be pretty much the same. Didn't think of the default case possibly obscuring additional warnings.